# get JSONObject from httpURLConnection and parsing into ArrayList

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I tried a bit around getting single datarows from an mysql Database on an extern server. Until now it worked quite fine. Now I tried getting a JSONArray from the Server to show it in an ListView. I try to explain the problems I have.

Remark: I deleted the real url, it's tested, the url and the php-script both are working correct. If I type the url in my browser, the script delivers the requested data in JSON Format.

Here parts of my code:

```
    /**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {     //type must be a problem
        try {
            url = new URL("http://somewhere");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        }
        try {
            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // setDoInput and setDoOutput method depict handling of both send and receive
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // Post Parameter an URL anhängen
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("loge", params[0]);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            // Open connection for sending data
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        }
        try {
            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();
            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result.toString());
                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    return jsonObject.toString();       //this might be a problem
                   // return (result.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //if something went wrong, return null
                return null;
            } else {

                return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //no idea how to get ths JSONObject in the parameterlist and convert it to ArrayList
        ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();
        String jArray = (String) result;
        if (jArray != null) {
            for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                listdata.add(jArray(i));
            }
        }
```

First problem which type would be the choice for `doInBackground` function, also my return should be incorrect this way?
Second one, how to deliver the jsonObject to my function `onPostExecute`? which type ust be used in this position?
And last one, how can I get the content of the jsonObject variable to my ArrayList?

Besides: Yes, I read many other post and some tutorials, but I couldn't transfer the information I got to my example.

EDIT1:part of string, which comes from the server:

[{"nr":"317","datum":"2016-02-09","zeit":"19:30:00","thema":"","kopfnr":"2","typ":"2"},{"nr":"318","datum":"2016-02-23","zeit":"20:00:00","thema":"Wandern","kopfnr":"2","typ":"6"},{"nr":"319","datum":"2016-03-01","zeit":"18:45:00","thema":"Instruktion","kopfnr":"2","typ":"7"},{"nr":"320","datum":"2016-03-01","zeit":"20:00:00","thema":"Eine Schwester stellt sich vor","kopfnr":"2","typ":"7"},{"nr":"321","datum":"2016-03-08","zeit":"19:30:00","thema":"Der Spiegel","kopfnr":"2","typ":"5"},{"nr":"322","datum":"2016-03-22","zeit":"20:00:00","thema":null,"kopfnr":"2","typ":"6"}]

EDIT2: I followed the explanation the errors vanished and ! I understood how it works. Thx 
I have just one problem left, how to get the arraylist from `protected void onPostExecute( ArrayList<String> result)`
My former call of the asyncTask function was: new `LoadAllProducts().execute(loge);` but I probably can't `onPostExecute` change in an function with a returnvalue because it is called automatically during asyncTask process, right?
After that everything is finished I promise

Comment: Show String which getting from server in `result`

Comment: JSON String contains many items which you want to add in ArrayList?

Comment: I highly recommend you switch to using something like Retrofit. You can use a converter to automatically parse responses like this.

Comment: @orbit I don't know exactly what you mean, could you deliver an example please

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K yes, in the end I want to show all of the columns, for the beginning to have a better idea, how everything works, I'm happy if it shows nr :-)

Comment: A simple google search would of answered your question: [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First problem which type would be the choice for doInBackground
>   function

JSON String as in post is `JSONArray` of `JSONObject's` instead of `JSONObject`. create `JSONArray` from `result` in `doInBackground` :

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result.toString());
```

> how to deliver the jsonObject to my function onPostExecute?

Instead of `JSONObject` return `ArrayList` of items.

> how can I get the content of the jsonObject variable to my ArrayList?

Parse `jsonArray` to get all JSONObject's from it then get required value from each `JSONObject` and add it to `listdata`

```
ArrayList<String> listdata = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int n = 0; n < jsonArray.length(); n++)
{
    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(n);
    listdata.add(object.optString("nr")); 
}

return listdata;
```

Comment: I changed everything in doInBackground. With this return listdata.toString() I get a string in onPostExecute. Hm so how to bind result to my listview? Its in the same activity, name of avtivity is: public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity, listview is established in my xml file all_products.xml <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

Comment: @pia-sophie: NOT  `listdata.toString()` just return `listdata`

Comment: @pia-sophie: to show data in ListView pass `listdata` to your Adapter in `onPostExecute` method

Comment: then android studio shows an error: incompatible types, so I should change the return type of the function ..to what type ? protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... params)?

Comment: @pia-sophie: dude change `AsyncTask<String, String, String> ` to `AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<String>> ` and `onPostExecute( ArrayList<String> result)` no need to change `doInBackground(String... params)`

Comment: then I get in the functionshead of doInBackground incompatible returntypes, so I changed the returntype to ArrayList<String>